# USB Memory stick won't show on explorer

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

I have read about all questions similar to mine but none of them is describing my problem.

I purchased this 64GB USB memory stick from Fry's electronics about 3-4 months ago. SO the return period is long gone. Today, I took it out of its packaging and stick it to my dell workstation desktop, running windows 7. It finished installing the drivers. When I go to the device manager, I see it as USB mass storage device (and when I unplug it, that storage device disappears. So, I am sure it is that one.

But when I open the windows explorer, removable drive icon looks gray and it doesn't let me view it or format it or whatever. Unplugged it and took it to wife's win7 laptop. Same symptoms, this time it doesn't show up at all under windows explorer.

I tried updating drivers from device manager but update comes back saying, driver is up to date. I am stumped. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Likely, the device is defective. Try opening it in Windows *Disk Management*,  diskmgmt.msc,and see if it's described as "Healthy". If it is healthy, an formatted exFAT, try formatting it NTFS. **N.B.** NTFS is normally [*not* recommended for USB flash drives](https://serverfault.com/questions/41674/flash-drives-should-be-formatted-ntfs), but exFAT may be causing troubles on your PC's.

Also try another OS, e.g. Windows 10 or Ubuntu on a 64-bit machine. If it fails to work there, go back to Fry's anyway... what can you lose by asking for a replacement?

[image: Windows Disk Management]

Comment: On the disk management I see the drive letter (E:) it says Removable but it also says no media. So it sees a drive (controller for the lack of a better term) but there is no capacity behind that controller. This is my wild guess.

Comment: You can try formatting with DM, or with a third-party tool such as DiskGenius, https://www.diskgenius.com/download.php . If that doesn't work, the flash drive is truly Fry'd.